# How to migrate files a Dropbox app folder to another?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I have a chess app which can load and save chess records (PGN files) via Dropbox. The Dropbox access permission was all folders (which was popular in the old days). Recently, many users are writing to me for their concern of letting a chess app to access all Dropbox folders. So I am going to limit my app to a single app folder, i.e.: inside a `Dropbox/Apps/Chess` folder.

The question is, what is the proper way for the my app to migrate files from other folders to this `Dropbox/Apps/Chess` folder? As I will switch Dropbox API key during the process, how can I minimize the trouble for the users.

Comment: Dropbox API's provide webservices to move folder from one directory to another. Write a function to "migrate" which moves your files from all other directory to one directory.

Comment: Once you switched the app key, it would not be possible to access folders outside your app folder.  Your users might have to using a web browser or Dropbox app to move it themselves.

Comment: Right, using the new app key, you won't be able to access files outside the app folder. You can have the user authorize the new app first, and then use the old app key/access token to move the existing files into the newly created app folder (since the old app with full access has access to both.)

Comment: Greg, what does an app have to do to switch between app keys dynamically?